# Compiling and running c++ programm in PHP

Tags: php, c++, compilation

I want to make a online compiler.

I'm testing all my codes on computer (i installed php).

I wrote this code to compile, but it's not working (i was searching for too hours, but i didn't find a

```
<?php
$file="prog.cpp";

function kompiluj(){
    global $file;

    $polecenie = 'g++ '.$file.' -o a.exe ';

    global $errorFlag;
    global $errorDetail;
    $output = exec($polecenie, $errorDetail, $errorFlag);
    echo $errorDetail;
    echo $errorFlag;
    echo $output;
}

?>
```

Maybe somebody know to repair this? Thanks u very much :P

--EDIT:

For example my prog.cpp looks like

```
include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
cout<<"TEST";
return 0;
}
```

My function should write "TEST", but it's only has written:

Array
1

How I can do?

Comment: Uh, exactly what happens/doesn't happen, and how is that different from what you expect?

Comment: The 'geordi - C++ eval bot' (http://www.eelis.net/geordi/) might be interesting.

Comment: It doesn't look like you are calling the function there, is this the whole file's contents?

Comment: I call this function in other file, where cpp is saving from textbox - those working great.

Comment: Don't use echo to output debugging info, use var_dump() instead. For example, the 'Array' is from using echo with an Array. Normally, converting an array to a string also causes some diagnostic output, which should have told you about that. Make sure that you don't turn those diagnostics off, they are important! That said, there are many things that can be wrong, try starting a different program, try running the code from the commandline (not via the browser) and check the mentioned error logs for a start.

Comment: I changed echo to var_dump() and result is : array(0) { } 
int(1) 
string(0) ""

Comment: Nice, so now check the documentation what that means: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php. Also make sure you understand all the warnings and usage notes. Concerning the user comments, take care that not everyone there is voicing an informed opinion, sometimes the comments there are misleading. Oh, what about all the other points I raised in the previous comment?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the PHP documentation if `exec` calls a shell or not, but even if it does, it probably provides a minimal environment. Either way you will probably need to provide the full path to `g++`. Try changing this:

```
$polecenie = 'g++ '.$file.' -o a.exe ';
```

... to this:

```
$polecenie = '/usr/bin/g++ '.$file.' -o a.exe ';
```

... and be sure to verify the full path to `g++`.

Comment: I change this to: $polecenie = 'g++ '.$file.' -o a.exe ';, but it doesn't working too ;(

Comment: Did you try `$polecenie = '/usr/bin/g++ '.$file.' -o a.exe ';`? That's what I was suggesting.

Comment: Yes, i tried it. I changed echo to var_dump() too, but it's not working. Result is: array(0) { } 
int(1) 
string(0) ""

Too, i tried to chnage to : $polecenie = 'C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++ '.$file.' -o a.exe ';

Comment: C:\\MinGW\\bin\\  , because as i wrote i'm testing it on my pc with installed php

Comment: You will need to check your web server error logs. It sounds like you may have permissions problems, or a munged file path.